# PHP "while" loop is not executing second command for each loop

Tags: php

I have a text file with three words in it; each on a separate row: child, toy, people.
I am using the Laravel **Str::plural()** function to pluralize each word and display the results with line breaks.

It works perfectly when I use the words in my code without a file, as so:

```
        $output1 = Str::plural('child');
        $output2 = Str::plural('toy');
        $output3 = Str::plural('person');

        $string = $output1 . "\r\n" . $output2 . "\r\n" . $output3;
        echo nl2br($string);
```

The result shows as follows:

```
children
toys
people
```

However, when I use a "while" loop through a file containing these words, it only pluralizes the last word.

This is the "while" loop code:

```
$myFile = new \SplFileObject("words.txt");

while (!$myFile->eof()) {

     $string = Str::plural($myFile->fgets());
     echo nl2br($string);
}
```

As you can see from the result, only the last word is pluralized:

```
child
toy
people
```

Since my loop has brackets {} I assumed that BOTH lines of codes execute for each loop but I guess in PHP it's not like that? Any idea how to fix my "while" loop?

Comment: Your loop is probably only executing once, and you are passing the entire string into the function, not individual words. It is possible this is a [line-ending problem](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php#refsect1-function.fgets-notes).

Comment: It works for me locally, so I agree that it's a line-ending problem. Try `$str = trim($myFile->fgets());
    $string = Str::plural($str);`

Comment: @aynber works great, just the "trim" is putting all the words into one word (no spaces: childrentoyspeople) and my nl2br is not working (maybe it would work if there were spaces in between the words.) Since I'm new to PHP, I'll just research the trim function  - but now it works! Thanks. You can put this as an answer (and maybe add the trim fix too)

Comment: @ChrisHaas I see that article is talking about a MAC. I'm on a PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some extra spaces or line-ending characters, so you'll need to trim the string before you pluralize it.

```
$str = trim($myFile->fgets()); // Remove white space from the word/line
$string = Str::plural($str);
```

However, the nl2br will not work since there are no longer any new lines, so you'll want to append the br to the words.

```
echo "$string<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have written words in file on separate rows;
It means that of the end of each row you have hidden symbols \r\n
I can say it because "person" is pluralized correclty and there is no other words after that in your example.
You can easy check it with debug or var_dump function;

```
echo var_dump($yourString);
```

You will see something like this

```
string(5) "toy
"
```